# Ошибка Телеграм бот "Bad Request: BUTTON_URL_INVALID

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Здравствуйте. Пишу телеграм бота на питон, использую библиотеку [pyTelegramBot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#reply-markup)

Вот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def handler_command_help(message):


    b_1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Москва",callback_data="Москва")
    markup_city = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup_city.add(b_1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, texts.start_message, reply_markup=markup_city)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "Москва":
        setCity_in_DB(call,call.message.chat.id)
        getDName(call)
```

При нажатии на кнопку вылетает ошибка:

```
 ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
 [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: 
 BUTTON_URL_INVALID"}']"
```

Не могу понять в чём проблема?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45317041/4269118

Comment: заведите уже там ишью

Comment: Ответ есть на en.so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45317041/2790048